# traefik not running on new node in docker swarm

Tags: docker, traefik, swarm

i created a new linux node and add this to the docker swarm cluster.
now the traefik stack will deployed also on this node, but it failed and i see now errors.

in the logs it only starting the file provider but then it stops and the healthcheck fails.

```
time="2022-07-21T17:34:23Z" level=info msg="Starting provider aggregator aggregator.ProviderAggregator"
time="2022-07-21T17:34:23Z" level=info msg="Starting provider *file.Provider"
```

traefik config

```
providers:
  file:
    directory: /etc/traefik/config.d
    watch: false

  docker:
    endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    swarmMode: true
    exposedByDefault: false
    network: "traefik"
    swarmModeRefreshSeconds: 10

  consul:
    rootKey: "traefik"
    endpoints:
      - "consulagent:8500"
```

other services already deployed and running on new node.

does anyone got same issue?
whats the problem here?

!! Update 1
i added the compose file.
now i paused the new node and now i have the problem on existing nodes.
the traefik will not start correct, and is only starting file.provider and then the healthcheck failed

```
---
version: '3.7'
services:
  traefik:
    deploy:
      labels:
        com.docker.compose.version: "%1$s"
        com.docker.compose.commit: "%2$s"
        com.docker.compose.build_date: "%3$s"
        com.docker.compose.vcs_url: "%4$s"

      restart_policy:
        condition: any

      mode: global
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
    
    image: %5$s

    environment:
      CONSUL_HTTP_TOKEN: '#{CONSUL_HTTP_TOKEN}'

    ports:
      - target: 8080
        published: 8080
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
      - target: 80
        published: 80
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
      - target: 443
        published: 443
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
      - target: 9300
        published: 9300
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
      - target: 9200
        published: 9200
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host

    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-fks", "-o", "/dev/null", "http://localhost:8080/ping"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 4

    networks:
      connect:

    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /mnt/data/traefik_log:/var/log/traefik
      - /mnt/gv0/certificate-robot/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt:ro

networks:
  connect:
    external: true
```

Comment: Could you include the compose file for the stack this is running in?

Comment: @MrDiggles i added the compose file.

Comment: Nothing looks obviously incorrect to me - can you update the log level to `DEBUG` and see what it prints out? https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/observability/logs/

Comment: i already tried to raise the loglevel, but the output was the same, stops after file.provider

Comment: Are you sure you're rebuilding the image after making the change? There should be significantly more output even if the configuration is wrong.

Comment: im sure, because the other nodes logged more and the debug logs also

Comment: i dont know why, but the start of the traefik tooks longer then usually and then the healthcheck kills the container. i increased the retries and now the traefik needs 2min to start and then everything is fine.